# remove commas from stringified JSON but not commas separating array

Tags: jquery, json, replace, stringify

I have stringified JSON data that contains commas in description fields.  The AJAX post fails if I have apostrophes OR commas in the data. 
 How can I strip the following from my `var test = JSON.stringify(data)`

test would print out as follows:

**`[{"var1":"0","description":"this, has, commas"},{"var1":"1","description":"more, commas"}]`**
can I strip out the commas in the description so the JSON string lookes like:
`[{"var1":"0","description":"this has commas"},{"var1":"1","description":"more commas"}]` 
and so leaving the commas that separate the objects?
or better yet...:
`[{"var1":"0","description":"this \\, has \\, commas"},{"var1":"1","description":"more \\, commas"}]`

Data needs to be pushed back to my server and loaded back into my DB after changes, commas and apostrophes need to remain in tact.
`test.replace(/,/g,"")` of course... gets rid of the commas that separate the objects also, and screws me up.
anyone know regex well, that could suggest a way to replace a "," but "not" when between a `"},{"` ? (double quotes are for emphasis)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not remove the commas from the elements, and then stringify the resulting array?

Comment: The data I supplied is only a sample, the data I'm using is enormous.  Pulling from a database, making modifications and pushing back to the server, not all the data I pull contain commas.  about 50K of data at a time.  I might add, it needs to be put back into my oracle DB "with" the commas and apostrophes.

Comment: Your problem is this: "The AJAX post fails if I have apostrophes OR commas in the data." You need your posts to work with arbitrary data.

Comment: Can you parse the JSON to an object, then look at each of the object's fields to replace "," with "\,", and re-stringify?

Comment: Why is the server failing when sent valid data?

Comment: Regex solution to my original post would be ideal, the data I'm working with is too huge for traversing over, besides, the commas and apostrophes need to be in tact for the upload, I need to escape them.

Comment: @jochanan There is a Regex answer that was posted below 25 minutes ago. Can you take a look and see if that will work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing the test.replace with a negative lookahead - https://regex101.com/r/WtHcuO/2/:

```js
var data = JSON.stringify([{"var1":"0","description":"this, has, commas"},{"var1":"1","description":"more, commas"}]);

var stripped = data.replace(/,(?!["{}[\]])/g, "");

console.log(stripped);
```

Or, if you want to preserve the commas, but escape them, you can replace with `\\,` instead of `""`

```js
var data = JSON.stringify([{"var1":"0","description":"this, has, commas"},{"var1":"1","description":"more, commas"}]);

var stripped = data.replace(/,(?!["{}[\]])/g, "\\,");

console.log(stripped);
```

Comment: Oh this is very clever.

Comment: Parsing json with regexp is ridiculous. Convert it back to object/array and do it properly (or do so before stringifying), if at all.

Comment: thanks mhodges, this is perfect... I'd give you a hundred up arrows if possible!  Thanks again!